# How can I grant access to array of admins on Firebase database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am stuck trying to allow an an array of admins access to their data.
I have a database structure like this:

```
{
    "Respondents": {
        "Acme Corp": {
            "admins": ["mMK7eTrRL4UgVDh284HntNRETmx1", ""mx1TERNmMK7eTrRL4UgVDh284Hnt"],
            "data": {data goes here...}
        },
        "Another Inc": {
            "admins": ["Dh284HmMK7eTrRL4UgVDh284HntN", ""x1TERNmx1TERNmMK7eTrRL4UgVDh"],
            "data": {their data goes here...}
        }
    }
}
```

And then I tried to set my rules like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Respondents": {
      "$organisation" : {
        ".read": "root.child('Respondents').child($organisation).child('admins').val().includes(auth.id)",
        ".read": "root.child('Respondents').child($organisation).child('admins').val().includes(auth.id)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

..but that won't parse in the Firebase Database Rules editor
I get "Error saving rules - Line 7: No such method/property 'includes'", but I need something to match the user id with the array of admins.
Any experience or suggestions?

Comment: Noticed a small, but important error in both question and answer: auth.id doesnt work. It is: auth.uid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found, there is no `includes()` operation in Firebase's security rules. This is because Firebase doesn't actually store the data as an array. If you look in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/) or read [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) you will see that Firebase stores it as a regular object:

```
"admins": {
  "0": "mMK7eTrRL4UgVDh284HntNRETmx1",
  "1": "mx1TERNmMK7eTrRL4UgVDh284Hnt"
}
```

And since that is a regular JavaScript object, there is no `contains()` method on it.

In general creating arrays are an anti-pattern in the Firebase Database. They're often the wrong data structure and when used are regularly the main cause of scalability problems.

In this case: you're not really looking to store a sequence of UIDs. In fact: the order of the UIDs doesn't matter, and each UID can be meaningfully present in the collection at most once. So instead of an array, you're looking to store **set** of uids.

To implement a set in Firebase, you use this structure:

```
"admins": {
  "mMK7eTrRL4UgVDh284HntNRETmx1": true, 
  "mx1TERNmMK7eTrRL4UgVDh284Hnt": true
}
```

The value doesn't matter much. But since you must have a value to store a key, it is idiomatic to use `true`.

Now you can test whether a key with the relevant UID **exists** under `admins` (instead of checking whether it contains a value):

```
"root.child('Respondents').child($organisation).child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()",
```

Comment: Frank your the man! Thanks for not only solving the problem, but also explaining a best practice

Comment: Noticed a small, but important error in both question and answer: auth.id doesnt work. It is: auth.uid

Comment: Good catch! I fixed it in the answer.